# Вопрос по ViewPager

Tags: java, android

Как из фрагментов ViewPager управлять View элементами того activity, где был создан этот ViewPager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо создать какой-то интерфейс который будет реализован в вашей активити.

Передать  экземпляр (this при условии что активити реализует ваш интерфейс) во фрагменты. И оттуда вызывать методы этого интерфейса.

Сейчас нет вспомню, но возможно сам ViewPager уже имеет контекст активити и тогда вам просто нужно этот контекст в методе фрагмента onAttach проверить на то что он является экземпляром вашего интерфейса и использовать его.